# Migrate from Python2 to Python 3.6.2 with TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I want to migrate from python2 to python3.
In code, it opens a file in binary mode like this.

```
f = open('test', 'rb+')
```

Because, it needs file seeking like this.

```
f.seek(-26, 1)
```

And, the code writes a formatted string to file.

```
f.writelines("%20s,%04d\n" % (varStr, varInt))
f.writelines('{0:>20s},{1:04d}\n'.format(varStr, varInt))
```

Upper code is original code and lower code is edited by me.
But, When I run a code, there is an error.

> TypeError: a bytes like object is required, not 'int'

Please, help me out from this hell.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Include the full traceback indicating the line of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes:

1. You need encode your strings when opening the file in binary mode (to change them in bytes)
2. writelines must be used with a list instead of a single item (the function has an 's' at the end). In your case, you can use 'write'

Maybe something like this will work:

```
f.write(("%20s,%04d\n" % (varStr, varInt)).encode())
f.write(('{0:>20s},{1:04d}\n'.format(varStr, varInt)).encode())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved this problem like this.

f.writelines(['{0:>20s},{1:04d}\n'.format(varStr, varInt).encode()])